# Write a polynomial of sixth degree from known zeros

Tags: polynomials

Write a sixth degree polynomial with real coefficients.

Known zeros:

$$ 3+2i , -2, ..and ..0(third..degree) $$

we know that at $$p(1)=8$$

I tried the following: $$p(x)=(x-3-2i)(x+2)(x-0)^3(x-x_3)$$

Then I calculated for $x_3$ from $p(1)=8$.

Is this procedure correct?

The solution for this problem is: $$\frac13(x^6-4x^5+x^4+26x^3)$$

Comment: are the coefficients real numbers?

Comment: Yes they are. I will edit immediately

Comment: The method seems to be correct, but you can always check your result with Wolfram Alpha for example. (See the comment from Winther below though)

Comment: in this case must the other solution be $$x=-3-3i$$

Comment: To write down the most general polynomial you also need a free constant infront, i.e. $p(x) = A(x-3-2i)\cdots$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The last root should be the conjugate $3-3i$, not the negative.

Comment: yes it must be $$x=3-3i$$ thank you it was surely a typo

Comment: The method is correct and, assuming you've made no mistakes, your answer should be also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
p(x)=a(x-3-2i)(x-3+2i)(x+2)x^3
$$
The condition $p(1)=8$ is equivalent to
$$
3a-1=0.
$$

Comment: Thanks very much. Can you explain to me why do we need to conjugate the complex number?

Comment: Because $f(z)=0$ implies $f(\overline{z})=\overline{f(z)}=\overline{0}=0$. Here $\overline{a+bi}=a-bi$.

Comment: Ok, but why do we have to use both a+bi and a-bi. Why isn't only one root enough?

Comment: Again, because if $f(z)=0$, then also $\overline{z}$ is a root, i.e., you can only have them in pairs. And if $f(\overline{z})=0$, then also $\overline{\overline{z}}=z$ is a root.

Comment: Yeah, but why do we have to multiply the roots and not do them seperately and get 2 solutions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem

Comment: You do not have to multiply the roots, but each root gives a linear factor of $p(x)$. So two roots $a$ and $b$ give linear factors $(x-a)(x-b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $3+2i$ is a root, $3-2i$ is also a root, as polynomials with real coefficients can only have complex conjugates if one solution is a complex number.

$[x-(3+2i)][x-(3-2i)]=[(x-3)-2i][(x-3)+2i] = (x-3)^2+4=x^2-6x+13$

I think you can figure out the rest with your other method.

Comment: May I know why this was downvoted?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you tell me let's say that the complex root is 3 power, so $(x-a-bi)^3$. Do we do conjugation $(x-a-bi)^3(x-a+bi)^3$ or like $((x-a-bi)(x-a+bi))^3$

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem)